# Composer error on update [UnexpectedValueException]

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I get this error when try to update composer.

Im using the comand:

```
composer update -v --no-dev
```

And i get this error (stack trace) below:

```
Adding VCS repository npm-asset/lodash.uniq 
Adding VCS repository npm-asset/lodash.without
Adding VCS repository npm-asset/mississippi   
Adding VCS repository npm-asset/mkdirp     


[UnexpectedValueException]                                          
Could not parse version constraint &&: Invalid version string "&&"  


Exception trace:
 () at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/composer/semver/src/VersionParser.php:485
 Composer\Semver\VersionParser->parseConstraint() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/composer/semver/src/VersionParser.php:244
 Composer\Semver\VersionParser->parseConstraints() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionParser.php:28
 Composer\Package\Version\VersionParser->parseConstraints() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:238
 Composer\Package\Loader\ArrayLoader->parseLinks() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Loader/ArrayLoader.php:122
 Composer\Package\Loader\ArrayLoader->load() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/NpmRepository.php:133
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository->createArrayRepositoryConfig() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/NpmRepository.php:79
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\NpmRepository->createVcsRepositoryConfig() at /root/.composer/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Repository/AbstractAssetsRepository.php:136
 Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Repository\AbstractAssetsRepository->whatProvides() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:204
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->computeWhatProvides() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Pool.php:193
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Pool->whatProvides() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:161
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromPackage() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:273
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->whitelistFromJobs() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php:324
 Composer\DependencyResolver\RuleSetGenerator->getRulesFor() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:214
 Composer\DependencyResolver\Solver->solve() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:473
 Composer\Installer->doInstall() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Installer.php:227
 Composer\Installer->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/UpdateCommand.php:161
 Composer\Command\UpdateCommand->execute() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:242
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:842
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:193
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:251
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:100
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/bin/composer:58
 require() at /usr/local/bin/composer:24
```

Anybody can help me find out what to do with this?

## **updating**

composer.json file:

```
{
    "name" : "yiisoft/yii2-app-basic",
    "description" : "Yii 2 Basic Project Template",
    "keywords" : [
        "yii2",
        "framework",
        "basic",
        "project template"
    ],
    "homepage" : "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type" : "project",
    "license" : "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support" : {
        "issues" : "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum" : "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki" : "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc" : "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source" : "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability" : "dev",
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2" : ">=2.0.11",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap" : "@dev",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-grid" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-mpdf" : "v1.0.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-editable" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-tabs-x" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-fileinput" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-money" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widgets" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-typeahead" : "*",
        "yiibr/yii2-br-validator" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-builder" : "@dev",
        "softark/yii2-dual-listbox" : "dev-master",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-popover-x" : "@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-export" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-detail-view" : "*",
        "bower-asset/Chart.js" : "*",
        "codeception/specify" : "*",
        "codeception/verify" : "*",
        "kartik-v/yii2-date-range" : "^1.6",
        "kartik-v/yii2-checkbox-x" : "*",
        "zendframework/zend-servicemanager" : "^2.7.5 || ^3.0.3",
        "bower-asset/toastr" : "^2.1",
        "cossou/jasperphp" : "2.3.0",
        "endroid/qr-code" : "~2.4.0",
        "nfephp-org/posprint" : "^0.1",
        "nfephp-org/sped-nfe" : "^4.1@dev",
        "nfephp-org/sped-da" : "*"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "codeception/codeception" : "2.1.*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug" : "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii" : "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker" : "*"
    },
    "config" : {
        "process-timeout" : 1800
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "post-create-project-cmd" : "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject"
    },
    "extra" : {
        "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject" : {
            "setPermission" : [{
                    "runtime" : "0777",
                    "web/assets" : "0777",
                    "yii" : "0755"
                }
            ],
            "generateCookieValidationKey" : [
                "config/web.php"
            ]
        },
        "asset-installer-paths" : {
            "npm-asset-library" : "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library" : "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
```

The composer is already updated to last version, and there seems to be no "&&" constraint error. When i run composer update on my local machine it works fine, but when i do the same on server it return this error.

Comment: appears to be an invalid composer.json file, can you share it, or try a `composer self-update` and then try again

Comment: There should not be something like `&&` in a version constraint, so please attach your `composer.json` or look for such an erronous constraint

Comment: @Dale Updated with composer.json file.

Comment: @NicoHaase When i execute the composer update with same composer file on my local machine it works, but on server it returns this error.

Comment: Do you run composer locally and on your server with the same PHP version?

Comment: Does version of `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` plugin differs between production and dev environment?

Comment: @NicoHaase local is using PHP 7.0 and server is still on 5.6, could be this?

Comment: @rob006 sorry, but how to i check this?

Comment: @BigBoss Try `composer global show fxp/composer-asset-plugin`.

Comment: @rob006 local and server was with different versions. Updated both and i gonna try again.

Comment: Updating fxp/composer-asset-plugin worked for this problem, probably i gonna have to update php too.
Other problems appeared though, but this one is solved. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, what solved for me is check the versions of fxp/composer-asset-plugin on local and on the server. Updating both solved my problem.

Check version:

```
composer global show fxp/composer-asset-plugin
```

Update version:

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3"
```

Is always good to check PHP version too.